# ERROR: rtpproxy [rtpproxy.c:1681]: send_rtpp_command(): can't send command to a RTP proxy

Tags: debian, rtp, kamailio

I am trying to enable RTPPROXY on debian, but it seems RTPProxy is ignoring my arguments...

So, I am launching RTPPROXY using command:

> rtpproxy -l _MY_PUBLIC_IP_ -s udp:127.0.0.1 7722 -p /var/run/rtpproxy.pid -R -a -P -r /tmp/rtppath -S /tmp/rtpspool -u rtpproxy rtpproxy

Also tried with:

> rtpproxy -l _MY_PUBLIC_IP_ -s udp:127.0.0.1 7722 -u rtpproxy rtpproxy

And when I try to start Kamailio service I am getting error:

> 0(10562) ERROR: rtpproxy [rtpproxy.c:1681]: send_rtpp_command(): can't send command to a RTP proxy 
>   0(10562) ERROR: rtpproxy [rtpproxy.c:1716]: send_rtpp_command(): proxy  does not respond, disable it
>   0(10562) WARNING: rtpproxy [rtpproxy.c:1573]: rtpp_test(): can't get version of the RTP proxy
>   0(10562) WARNING: rtpproxy [rtpproxy.c:1610]: rtpp_test(): support for RTP proxy  has been disabled temporarily

p.s. I have checked RTPPROXY, and I am sure that it is launched

> ps aux | grep rtpproxy

returned me:

> root      2770  0.0  0.0  19392   480 ?        Ssl  04:59   0:00 /usr/bin/rtpproxy -l _MY_PUBLIC_IP_  -s udp:127.0.0.1 7722 -p /var/run/rtpproxy.pid -R -a -P -r /tmp/rtppath -S /tmp/rtpspool -u rtpproxy rtpproxy 
>   root      2775  0.0  0.0  11740   932 pts/1    S+   04:59   0:00 grep --color=auto rtp

Which says everything is ok and rtpproxy is running with arguments that I declared

But the problem is, When I check it with:

> netstat -tulpn | grep rtpproxy

I am receiving:

> udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:22222         0.0.0.0:*                           2853/rtpproxy

As you can see rtpproxy is listening on port 22222 and completely ignoring arguments I declared :(

Where and What am I doing wrong?

Sorry for my English and Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved problem... correct way to launch was:

> rtpproxy -l _MY_PUBLIC_IP_ -s udp:127.0.0.1:7722 -u rtpproxy rtpproxy